# Why I still can use Capybara method inside Rails Rspec Type Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

According to [Rspec Request Specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-6/docs/request-specs/request-spec)

> Capybara is no longer supported in request specs as of Capybara 2.0.0.

Why I still can use Capybara methods from inside Request specs; such as `visit`, `click_link`, `click_button`?

My related `Gemfile.lock` entries:

```
capybara (~> 2.15.1)
rspec-rails (~> 3.5, >= 3.5.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because you’re including `Capybara::DSL into all of your test types. Check your code for something like

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
   config.include Capybara::DSL # includes into every type of test
  ...
```

and remove the include line, it should already be correctly configured by requiring ‘capybara/rspec’.

Comment: oh great, you are right! but without requiring 'capybara/rspec', the specs are still working.

Comment: @siriusdely RSpec-Rails requires it - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/vendor/capybara.rb